# How do i convert const wchar_t* to System::String?

Tags: .net, string, c++-cli, wchar-t

I need to convert my SHA1 (wchar_t*) to a normal String^ in order to use it in a certain function. Any ideas? I tried Google but all the results were the exact opposite of my question. :\

NOTE: I am using C++.NET framework and Windows Forms Applications

Comment: @Dan Errors occur. Error 2 error C2664: 'System::String::String(const wchar_t *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const wchar_t *' c:\users\jeremy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\launcher\launcher\Form1.h 289

Comment: It's probably a bit late,  but a raw SHA1 hash stored in 10 `wchar_t` objects a) is quite likely not to be valid Unicode (invalid characters, invalid surrogate s); b) has a 1 in 1000 chance of containing an embedded NULL (which means just using gcnew will truncate).  If the OP is converting from a hex representation, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the constructor; like this:

```
const wchar_t* const pStr1 = ...;
System::String^ const str1 = gcnew System::String(pStr1);

const char* const pStr2 = ...;
System::String^ const str2 = gcnew System::String(pStr2);
```

If you're using the standard C++ string classes (`std::wstring` or `std::string`), you can get a pointer with the `c_str()` method.  Your code then might be

```
const std::wstring const std_str1 = ...;
System::String^ const str1 = gcnew System::String(std_str1.c_str());
```

See [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y4za026.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) and extensive discussion [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If on doing Dan's solution you get an error `cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const wchar_t *'`, then you're asking the wrong question. Instead of asking how to convert `wchar_t*` to `String^`, you should be asking how to convert `std::string` to `String^`.

Use the built-in `c_str` function to get a plain `char*` out of the `std::string`, and pass that to the constructor.

```
std::string unmanaged = ...;
String^ managed = gcnew String(unmanaged.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

...

String^ managedString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<String^>(/* std::string or wchar_t * or const wchar_t * */);
```

You can refer to [Overview of Marshaling in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) for all the supported types you could use